# iOS MKMapView viewForOverlay not called

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm losing my mind here. Why is this not working?? update_map method gets called but viewForOverlay doesn't.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(mapView2 != nil)
    {
        [self update_map];
    }

- (void)update_map
{
    CLLocationDistance fenceDistance = 100000;

    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:newCoord radius:fenceDistance];
    [mapView2 addOverlay:circle];
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    NSLog(@"circle overlay");
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc initWithOverlay:overlay];
    [circleView setFillColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [circleView setAlpha:0.1f];
    return circleView;
}
```

Comment: A map view sends messages to its delegate regarding the loading of map data and changes in the portion of the map being displayed. I am wondering, if you've set the delegate?

Comment: make sure mapView isn't nil and the delegate is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your view controller supports `<RKMapViewDelegate>` protocol and the `delegate` property for `mapView2` instance is set to your view controller, either in the .xib or programmatically as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.mapView2.delegate = self;
}
```